# How do I grab a single attribute from a Collection of objects that I group into a list?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have two lists that I'm trying to join based on a Group => ID and Artist => GroupID.

When I show groups, I want to show all the members in the group from the Artists list.

> ```
>             var groupID = from Group in allGroups
>                           join Artist in allArtists
>                           on Group.Id equals Artist.GroupId
>                           into Members
>                           where Group.Id == id
>                           select new
>                           {
>                               Group = Group.GroupName,
>                               Members
>                           };
>             return Json(groupID);
> ```

When the JSON data renders in the browser, I get all the data from each artist and I just want to show the name. See below:

> [{"group":"G-Unit","members":[{"artistName":"Lloyd Banks","realName":"Christopher Lloyd","age":34,"hometown":"New York City","groupId":2,"group":null},{"artistName":"The Game","realName":"Jayceon Taylor","age":37,"hometown":"Compton","groupId":2,"group":null},{"artistName":"50 Cent","realName":"Curtis Jackson","age":41,"hometown":"New York City","groupId":2,"group":null}]}]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Note: your source is not JSON, it is (joined) .NET Enumerables or Collections or Arrays. Only your output is JSON.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
var groupID = from Group in allGroups
                      join Artist in allArtists
                      on Group.Id equals Artist.GroupId
                      into Members
                      where Group.Id == id
                      select new
                      {
                          Group = Group.GroupName,
                          Members = Members.Select(e => e.artistName)
                      };
        return Json(groupID);
```

Comment: This line creates list of strings, not list of members so you must do like this: `Members.Select(e => new Member(){artistName = e.artistName})`

Comment: either solution is great. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, don't catch this is anonymous type :) Correct

Comment: @OzzyGonzalez Remember to select this answer as 'accepted answer'. It will help others with similar problems.